# How to simulate stageVideo in FDT AIR Application for IOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, fdt

I am trying to create an app that uses stageVideo and when testing on ipad device it is working fine, but when testing on desktop the STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY listener it is never AVAILABLE. I did put in the direct in the app.xml file.
Any ideas how to configure the FDT to have stageVideo available?

Answer (score 0):

There are aspects that you have to keep in mind:

- StageVideo is not supported on all platforms, i.e. on those without hardware acceleration. You can test on a newer machine if you have one to verify.
- Make sure you're running on AIR 3+.
- `StageVideoAvailabilityEvent` only fires when `Stage.stageVideos` property changes.
- If window transparency is set to true, then the window “falls back” to software rendering and blitting, see [Main window properties documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS2d929364fa0b81374fa5df4f129dca62884-8000.html#WS2d929364fa0b81374fa5df4f129dca62884-7ffc)

Your case probably falls into one of the 4 scenarios.